# Quicker way of transforming matrices in r?

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to transform a matrix according to various rules.

Take this matrix, m:

```
x<-c(NA,0,0,0,0,0,4,NA,0,0,1,1,0,0,NA,0,2,4,4,1,3,NA,2,3,0,1,2,0,NA,1,0,0,0,0,0,NA)
m<-matrix(x,6,6, byrow=T)
rownames(m)<-colnames(m)<-LETTERS[1:6]
m

#   A  B  C  D  E  F
#A NA  0  0  0  0  0
#B  4 NA  0  0  1  1
#C  0  0 NA  0  2  4
#D  4  1  3 NA  2  3
#E  0  1  2  0 NA  1
#F  0  0  0  0  0 NA
```

The rules for transforming it are as follows:

1) The diagonal should remain NA.

2) For all instances where m[i,j]>m[j,i]  then m[i,j] gets a '1' and m[j,i] gets a 0.

3) For all instances where m[i,j]==m[j,i]  AND both are NOT EQUAL to 0, then m[i,j] and m[j,i] should both get assigned 0.5

4) When m[i,j] and m[j,i] both are equal to 0, then one of them should randomly get a '1' and the other should get a '0'.

I can do steps 1-3 with this calculation:

```
 m1 <- (m > t(m))+0 + (((m == t(m)) & (m!=0 & t(m)!=0)) + 0)/2
 m1
```

which gives:

```
#   A   B   C  D   E  F
#A NA 0.0 0.0  0 0.0  0
#B  1  NA 0.0  0 0.5  1
#C  0 0.0  NA  0 0.5  1
#D  1 1.0 1.0 NA 1.0  1
#E  0 0.5 0.5  0  NA  1
#F  0 0.0 0.0  0 0.0 NA
```

Now I need to do step 4.  The instances where m1[i,j] and m1[j,i] are both equal to 0 in this matrix can be found with:

```
(m1==0 & t(m1)==0)

   #       A     B     C     D     E     F
   # A    NA FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
   # B FALSE    NA  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # C  TRUE  TRUE    NA FALSE FALSE FALSE
   # D FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE FALSE
   # E  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA FALSE
   # F  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE    NA
```

which shows that the instances are AC/CA, AE/EA, AF/FA, BC/CB.

An example of the output I am looking for :

```
#   A   B   C  D   E  F
#A NA 0.0 1.0  0 0.0  0
#B  1  NA 1.0  0 0.5  1
#C  0 0.0  NA  0 0.5  1
#D  1 1.0 1.0 NA 1.0  1
#E  1 0.5 0.5  0  NA  1
#F  1 0.0 0.0  0 0.0 NA
```

I know that it's possible to assign to both the upper and lower triangle the same values, e.g. NA in this code:     `m1[((m1==0 & t(m1)==0))] <- NA`   , but not sure how that is relevant here.   I could also melt the matrix into a pairwise list and do a long winded solution - but the purpose of this is to run thousands of simulations and so speed is very, very important.

Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe this is more complicated than it needs to be, but it works and it is all vectorized:

```
i <- m1==0 & t(m1)==0 & lower.tri(m1)
m1[i] <- sample(0:1, sum(i), replace = TRUE)
m1[t(i)] <- 1 - m1[i][order(row(i)[i], col(i)[i])]
```

**Edit:** Here is a second method using indexing by a matrix, maybe a little less complicated:

```
i <- which(m1==0 & t(m1)==0 & lower.tri(m1), TRUE)
z <- sample(0:1, nrow(i), replace = TRUE)
m1[i[, 1:2]] <- z
m1[i[, 2:1]] <- 1 - z
```